# Archive Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-type-archives

I need to apply this rewrite rule to multiple custom post types.

Currently it is only using one cpt "articles" but i need it to apply to "articles" & "newsletters"

How do i change the code to both these custom post types

```
/**
* Custom post type specific rewrite rules
* @return wp_rewrite Rewrite rules handled by WordPress
*/
function cpt_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite)
{
// Here we're hardcoding the CPT in, article in this case
$rules = cpt_generate_date_archives('article', $wp_rewrite);
$wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
return $wp_rewrite;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'cpt_rewrite_rules');

/**
* Generate date archive rewrite rules for a given custom post type
* @param  string $cpt slug of the custom post type
* @return rules       returns a set of rewrite rules for WordPress to handle
*/
function cpt_generate_date_archives($cpt, $wp_rewrite)
{
$rules = array();

$post_type = get_post_type_object($cpt);
$slug_archive = $post_type->has_archive;
if ($slug_archive === false) {
    return $rules;
}
if ($slug_archive === true) {
    // Here's my edit to the original function, let's pick up
    // custom slug from the post type object if user has
    // specified one.
    $slug_archive = $post_type->rewrite['slug'];
}

$dates = array(
    array(
        'rule' => "([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})",
        'vars' => array('year', 'monthnum', 'day')
    ),
    array(
        'rule' => "([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})",
        'vars' => array('year', 'monthnum')
    ),
    array(
        'rule' => "([0-9]{4})",
        'vars' => array('year')
    )
);

foreach ($dates as $data) {
    $query = 'index.php?post_type='.$cpt;
    $rule = $slug_archive.'/'.$data['rule'];

    $i = 1;
    foreach ($data['vars'] as $var) {
        $query.= '&'.$var.'='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index($i);
        $i++;
    }

    $rules[$rule."/?$"] = $query;
    $rules[$rule."/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"] = $query."&feed=".$wp_rewrite->preg_index($i);
    $rules[$rule."/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"] = $query."&feed=".$wp_rewrite->preg_index($i);
    $rules[$rule."/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$"] = $query."&paged=".$wp_rewrite->preg_index($i);
}
return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*@DarrenLee*, to add multiple post types on your code, you just make a change on function `cpt_rewrite_rules`. Create an array of your post types, put function `cpt_generate_date_archives` inside loop.

```
function cpt_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite)
{
    $post_types = array( 'book', 'movie', 'etc' ); //create post_types array

    $rules = array();
    foreach( $post_types as $post_type )
    {
        /* generate date archives */
        $rule = cpt_generate_date_archives( $post_type, $wp_rewrite );
        foreach( $rule as $k => $v )
            $rules[ $k ] = $v;
    }

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules; // combine rules

    return $wp_rewrite;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'cpt_rewrite_rules');
```

Comment: You're welcome, success for your work.